# Move <img> on a div hover

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make that an image that is inside a div moves without move other thing inside the div, this is my code:

```
<a href="#">
    <div id="cont" align="center">
        <img id="img_nav" src="img/menu_galeria.png">
        <p class="text_nav">Galeria</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

and this is my css:

```
#cont{
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#cont:hover > #img_nav{
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

Comment: I think we need more information here. Where is #img_nav supposed to move too? What triggers the moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adjusting the margin...just move the position of the image up:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #cont
    {
        margin-top: 15px;
        float: right;
        margin-left: 20px;
    }
    #cont:hover > #img_nav
    {
        position: relative;
        top: -5px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding zindex or clear property to your css properties like this

```
#cont:hover{
    margin-top: -5px;
    z-index:999;
    clear:both;
    position:absolute;
}
```